# Header in collection view won't show up? Used to work?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, imessage-extension

I migrated this project (an iMessage app with a collection view to hold stickers) from Swift 3 to Swift 5, and everything works but the header view function simply will not fire, nor will header show up.

I register the header cell in storyboard:

[image]

then in collection view functions:

```
private func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView: HeaderCollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView

        print("CALLED")
        //header1 = headerView as! UICollectionReusableView

        return headerView
    }
```

Ive even tried turning the header a different color in storyboard, however this function doesn't even print to console. What is wrong here? This used to work and the other cells work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I migrated this project (an iMessage app with a collection view to hold stickers) from Swift 3 to Swift 5

Well you didn't migrate this line:

```
private func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, 
                 atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
```

Change it to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, 
                          at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
```

Not `private`. Not `atIndexPath`. Not `NSIndexPath`. Talk Swift, not Objective-C, and don't hide this method from Objective-C or it can't be called by Cocoa.

Plus make absolutely sure you are in a place where adoption of UICollectionViewDataSource is declared (you probably are, since you say other methods are being called okay).